# Lambda returning Http 200 on timeout to API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function for which the timeout is set to 10 seconds. This lambda is triggered from an API Gateway. Now in my case, I could see in the cloudwatch logs that I am getting a Time out error `Task timed out after 10.00 seconds` which is fine. But the Response code I am getting in my API gateway logs is `Http-200`.

I read few AWS docs and answers on Stack Overflow regarding this issue that if this is something which is expected or there is some issue with my code, but none of them seems to give clear answer as many of the questions are too old to follow.

Also I did not find anything substantial in AWS docs as well.

Comment: Hey, any insights since you've asked your question?

Answer (score 3):

As per AWS,

> For Lambda custom integrations, you must map errors returned by Lambda
>   in the integration response to standard HTTP error responses for your
>   clients. Otherwise, Lambda errors are returned as 200 OK responses by
>   default and the result is not intuitive for your API users.

[Error Handling here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html)

You have to explicitly handle such errors.

Comment: In my cloudformation template for API Gateway, I have `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` and in this I have configured `'.*(Task timed out|"httpStatus":"503")`. But is this what I should have done ? I mean I have ```x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: '200'``` So if i change something for this then correct 200 will also be changed. right ? I am not sure if I am understanding it correctly or not

Comment: It would make more sense to make default 5xx or 4xx and return 2xx for know lamda calls.As handling of success status code is know to us and any other exception would be error

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled across this as well. 
In my scenario I was generally wondering what API Gateway returns when the lambda execution times out, runs out of memory etc. and found an answer in the aws forum:

[AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251824)

> The Lambda error regex is only applied when an execution result failed like the exception was thrown or marked as failed inside your Lambda function. If the exception is failed by Lambda service like access denied, throttled, etc, the regex will not be applied.

One possible solution could be to use the API Gateway as a lambda proxy. Then it actually maps all the *service* errors to an HTTP-502 response.

The thread in the forum I linked also mentions to use the invocation type *event*. Maybe that helps.

Comment: this is not true. Regex will still be applied in case of task time out from lambda